# How to read id with loop from list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, list, c#-4.0, for-loop, foreach

here is my code:

```
public class ListData
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int LinkedUserId { get; set; }
}

List<ListData> DataList = new List<LinkData>();

using (SqlConnection SqlConnections = new SqlConnection(Global.con))
using (SqlCommand SqlCommands = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,LinkedUserID From Users", SqlConnections))
{
    SqlConnections.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader SqlDataReaders = SqlCommands.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        while (SqlDataReaders.Read())
        {
            ListData newItem = new ListData();
            newItem.Id = SqlDataReaders.GetInt32(0);
            newItem.LinkedUserId = SqlDataReaders.GetInt32(1);

            DataList.Add(newItem);
        }

        SqlDataReaders.Close();
   }
```

There is a ListData class there is a two Ids one is Id and sec is LinkedUserId. I want to read both id from ListData and return one by one from running loop. I want to do something like that below:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < DataList .Count; i++)
            {
                string id = DataList[i].ToString();
            }
```

Does anybody have any idea how can i return value form for loop or using foreach loop?

Thank you

Comment: What is `links[i]`? Show complete code of `for (`

Comment: its DataList[i] not a links[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?:

```
    var result = new int[DataList.Count*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < DataList.Count; i++)
    {
        result[i * 2] = DataList[i].Id;
        result[i * 2 + 1] = DataList[i].LinkedUserId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ListData listData in DataList)
{
    string id = Convert.ToString(listData.Id);
    string linkedUserId = Convert.ToString(listData.LinkedUserId);
}
```